# Change position of an associative array index in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array in PHP. i want to change position of an array index and its value.

```
Array
(
    [savedRows] => 1
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => System has Skipped this row, because you have enter not valid value "" for field "description" in sheat "Electronics Laptops" row number "4"
    )

    [success] => successfully saved.
)
```

to like this

```
Array
```

(
       [savedRows] => 1
       [success] => successfully saved.
       [errors] => Array
            (
                [0] => System has Skipped this row, because you have enter not valid value "" for field "description" in sheat "Electronics Laptops" row number "4"
            )
    )

i want to change **["errors"]** index position from second to last and **[success]** index position at second when ever this array build. This is a dynamic array not a static it builds when a function call on function return i am getting this array.

Comment: Does it change anything in retrieving the data from Array? I'm sure it doesn't.

Comment: yes if i get array error index at second position my js not working properly on this that's need to change its position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array functions, but by far the easiest way to change it would be:

```
$newRow = ['savedRows' => $oldRow['savedRows'],
           'success'   => $oldRow['success'], 
           'errors'    => $oldRow['errors']];
```

But it is an associative array, not a numeric array, so order should not be that important.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i think this is the easiest way let me try like this

Comment: can i check success is exist or not in prev array in this process..??

Comment: I don't think I completely understand your question. If it is possible that `$oldRow['success']` does not exist you can check for its existance like this: `isset($oldRow['success']) ? $oldRow['success'] : 'failed'`. the 'failed' entry is just an example, it could be an empty string, or even `NULL`. The '? :' is called the ternary operator.

Answer (score 3):

You need not make this too complicated or use any fancy functions. Just follow a few simple steps.

- Store the errors sub array in another variable $errorField.
- Unset the array index "errors"
- Append this $errorField to a new key "errors".

  ```
  $errorField = $array['errors'];
  unset($array['errors']);
  $array['errors'] = $errorField;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Why does the order in the array matter?

If you really need that visually, you should initialize your array before you use it and overwrite the values when you fill it:

```
$arr = [
  'savedRows' => 0,
  'success' => '',
  'errors' => [],
]
// the rest of your code
```

Note that the order should not matter, if it does, you have another problem that you should fix.

Comment: this function called by ajax on success it behave differently when indexes are in diff position

Comment: @OBAID Then I am guessing that you are not sending json back and / or are not parsing it correctly. If you send json back, you can access all keys easily in javascript regardless of the order in the object.

Comment: ok let me try like this i think you are right i need to send json back properly